# R automatically apply the preprocessing realized on a dataset to a new dataset

Tags: r, automation, feature-engineering

I am looking for a way to write a fonction that loads automatically a part of a script in an other script.

Here my problem: I have created a script performing preprocessing on a dataset, then applying an xgboost.

I need to automatically apply the preprocessing realized (example: creation of new variables, replacement of NA by the mean - keeping the mean of the initial dataset) in this script to a new dataset. This should be totally transparent for users (no copy paste, only a function with the new set and a Rdata of the model to enter as arguments).

My idea was to "store" the part of the script with the preprocessing as an object in the Rdata, then when I load this object in the new script, the preprocessing is applied to the newdataset.

Does anybody has an idea of the way to do it?

Comment: put your preprocessing steps in a function?

Comment: that's what I am thinking. However, sometimes I will have to load the dataset, apply everything, et some other times I will have to retrieve some value then apply (by example, if I want to replace NA by the mean, I have to retrieve the mean in the initial dataset, not calculate the mean in the new dataset to replace. So that means that I will have to create several function, and a function that calls the functions created in a Rdata, I am not sure about the way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to implement a stable pipeline in `R`: save all preprocessing, transformation, and prediction steps for a big-data prediction implementation in one place.

While i currently would recommend using a dedicated pipelining tool and using that to call an `R`script in stead, there are some `R` packages that try to provide pipelining syntax, like `flowr`.

As you're doing an `xgboost` you may be able to leverage `Spark-ML`'s pipeline syntax via `sparklyr` as an intermediate solution, but it's still being very actively developed so may not yet work entirely as expected.

The open standard for saving ad sharing pipelines is `pmml`, and most frameworks have a way to *export* pipelines to `pmml` (`R` has the `pmml` package), but not to *import* them.

eta: for completeness, you can also try to wrap the necessary datastructure and the trained model object for each of your trained models into an `S4` class and define (highly specific) `preprocess()`, `transform()`, and `predict()` methods. I've done this for private use, but to me it has a bit too much of a ducttape-and-tiewrap feel to expose it to clients.

Comment: Many thanks, it's a great answer! I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

My answer obviously comes a little late, but maybe others like myself are working on their pipelines and stumble across this question. I suggest trying the `ProjectTemplate` package. It provides functions to automatically build a directory structure for a new R
project, using this structure, it automates data loading, preprocessing, library
importing etc. (e.g. for standard analyses I also have scripts for vizulizations, model building and automatic reports that I just run using `ProjectTemplate`). The pipeline is really efficient because you can `cache()` objects at every step and simply go from where you left off withour reruning same code. It is also quite customizable.